# is there some feature to limit the resource usage for the different users in gcp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to limit the resources that each user of the Google Cloud project can use but i don't find how I can do it. For example that one user only can create 2 vm in compute engine or limit the resources in a dataflow job (unrelated with the Quotas of the project).
Exists some feature to do it in the Google Cloud console?

I'm tried to use the organizational policies but they are not working or they are not enough specific to limit the resources in a dataflow job.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set limit per user. Google Cloud is project centric. You can set quotas on project, for instance, the max number of CPU usable (for instance 10 CPUs)

Like that, on the project, it will be possible to create:

- 1 Big VM with 10 cpu
- or 10 small VM with 1 CPU
- or 1 GKE cluster with 3 node, each one with 2 CPU, 1 small VM with 1 CPU and 1 dataflow with 3 CPUs max
  *...

You can also create one project per user and set the quota each project depending on the user.